# Angular -- Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a form with input fields. There are some default inputs fields values that come from a REST API.

Here is my template :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="action()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" [value]="fromApi(name)">
</form>
```

And my TS code :

```
 this.form = new FormGroup({name:new FormControl('')})
```

The client got his default value from the API. He can change that data in the input field.

There are two possibilities :

1) He does change the initial value coming from the API. In that cas when I console.log the FormGroup, I got the new value he entered, that's perfect !

2) He doesn't want to change the value from the API. And that's my problem : in that case, the value for the input name is '' (the value from FormControl). And I would like to have the value from the API.

Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: NOT use [value], take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337798/angular-reactive-form-cannot-set-property-of-undefined?rq=1 and use a function to fill the form

Answer (score 1):

sure it is.
fire your method to fetch from api in components `ngOnInit` hook and once you get data back (in subscribe, i guess) `patchValue` of the formControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.form = new FormGroup({name:new FormControl('')});
     this.fromApi();
}

fromApi(){
    //inside the subscribe method of the api called
    let valueFromAPI = 'Example';
    this.form.controls.name.setValue(valueFromAPI);
}
```

or

```
this.fromApi('name');

fromApi(control){
    //inside the subscribe method of the api called
    let valueFromAPI = 'Example';
    this.form.controls[control].setValue(valueFromAPI);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works but my example is pretty easy. My real form is really complex with plenty API calls from different URLs. I wish I could find a solution without any code !

Comment: From whichever API you get the value, inside its subscribe function you can use the setValue method of your form.

Comment: You can even make it dynamic. See the updated solution.

Comment: Normally you get from API an object and you want to reflect the data in your form. I don't understand use setValue, better give values when you create the FormControl

Comment: In case of multiple API calls for fetching the values, you cannot wait for the response of all the APIs in a synchronous way and then create a form. And you have to manage the same for add and edit functionality.