# How to let Angular Reactive Forms PatchValue() ignore null value or undefined when patching a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

For an application I'm building, I'm retrieving data from an API and setting my form value directly with that response. For that I'm using the reactive forms module. I've built the form so that it matches the object I'm getting from the API. The problem is that some fields are supposed to be an object (FormGroup), but are NULL when empty. This results in the error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

**FormGroup instance:**

```
note: this.formBuilder.group({
   turnbook_file: [''],
   note: [''],
   additional_files: ['']
});
```

**Response from API**

```
note: NULL
```

My thought was that maybe it's possibile to put an OR statement or something where you define the FormGroup like this:

```
note: this.formBuilder.group({
   turnbook_file: [''],
   note: [''],
   additional_files: ['']
} | NULL);
```

Comment: it's not my best answer, but I like make a function to create a FormGroup that received or data or null and use conditional operator to create the form filled or empy, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337798/angular-reactive-form-cannot-set-property-of-undefined?rq=1

Comment: @Eliseo I've seen a workaround like that. However, my groups sometimes go 3 layers deep. That means if i try to do it your way i would have 3 If statements in one line, which is (by my knowledge) not possible. IG: [data && data.note && data.note.author ? data.note.author : '']. This  would still result in an error "cannot find 'author' of undefined", if data.note would be undefined. But please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: For me work, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnwqyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please upvote the issue (Been open over a year) - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21021

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The title is about `patchValue` but in the question is about building the form. What's wrong with building/patching a first level control and only build/patch the second level group only after a check If you have a data?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using lodash pickBy method to wrap your api response before using it.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
...
//fetch data from API
note.patchValue(
    _.pickBy(apiResponse)
);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define your form like this

```
note =new FormGroup({
   'turnbook_file': new FormControl(null),
   'note: new FormControl(null),
   'additional_files': new FormControl(null)
})
```

Comment: Hi Prachi, thanks for your answer. However, it still gives me the same error because its still trying to convert null to an object. With your way, im saying the values may be null. I should be saying the object could also be null but i have no idea if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind

#### Modify FormGroup prototype

```
@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule {

  constructor() {
    const builtInFunction = FormGroup.prototype.patchValue;
    FormGroup.prototype.patchValue = function (value, options?) {
      builtInFunction.call(this, value || {}, options);
    }
  }

}
```

#### Extend FormGroup class

```
import {FormGroup, ValidatorFn, AbstractControlOptions, AsyncValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export class MyFormGroup extends FormGroup {

  constructor(
    controls: {[key: string]: any},
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null,
    asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
  ) {
    super(controls, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);  
  }

  patchValue(value: {[key: string]: any}, options: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}) {
    super.patchValue(value || {}, options);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:
In the current implementation of Angular Forms API - it's not possible to create/patch `FormGroup` with `null` or `undefined` value.

**Reason**: In all scenarios `new FormGroup(), formBuilder.group(), patchValue()` etc there is a call of a method `Object.keys()`, which throws an error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` (according to JS specification) if we pass `null/undefined` as argument.

**Proof**:

- `FormBuilder`'s `group()` method ([source code link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.0.2/packages/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L35-L79)):

  ```
    group(controlsConfig: {[key: string]: any}, ...) {
      const controls = this._reduceControls(controlsConfig);
      ...
    }
    _reduceControls(controlsConfig: {[k: string]: any}) {
      Object.keys(controlsConfig).forEach(...);
      ...
    }
  ```
- `FormGroup`'s `patchValue` ([source code link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.0.2/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1398-L1440)):

  ```
  patchValue(value: {[key: string]: any}, ...) {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(...);
    ...
  }
  ```

**Workarounds**:

- Change you API response in Backend side so it will send empty object `{}` instead of null;
- Once you receive a response in Frontend side, you can do mapping: from null to {};
- Extend `FormGroup` class and create a new one where you can override the `constructor/patchValue`: check if the argument is `null/undefined` - use empty object instead.
- Extend `FormBuilder` service and create your own Singleton service (use it everywhere in your app) where you can override the `group` method (see prev point).

Answer (score 1):

improving bestbrain10 answer. You can use pickBy and isDefined together.

```js
import { isEmpty, pickBy ,isUndefined,isNull} from 'lodash';
// Fetch data and remove all falsy  keys

this.formgroup.patchValue(
_.omitBy(formData, (v) => _.isUndefined(v) || _.isNull(v) || v === ''));
```

Comment: This worked for me... But with bestbrain10's import statement: `import * as _ from 'lodash';`. I cant figure out how yours would work?

Answer (score 0):

If you define form and controls then you have to must pass values to that so if your response is null then set values of Form controls like this

```
note.setValue({
'turnbook_file': data.turnbook_file == null ? "": data.turnbook_file,
   'note: ,data.note == null ? "": data.note,
   'additional_files': data.additional_files == null ? "": 
    data.additional_files,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter out those values before patching the form

```js
const obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: null,
  cat: undefined,
  dog: "bark"
}

const truthy = Object.keys(obj).filter(item => obj[item] != undefined || obj[item] != null );
const newObj = {};
truthy.forEach(item =>Object.assign(newObj, { [item]: obj[item]}));
console.log(newObj) // { foo: "bar", dog: "bark" }
```

Once you filter out the falsy values, just use it to patch the form